# python cx_oracle delete stmt error

Tags: python, oracle

I'm trying a delete a particular row from a table in a try except block but I get the following error

```
    self.returnvals['ERROR_CD']   = error.code
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'code'
```

Code:

```
try:
    # code deleting from a table
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, ex:
    error, = ex.args    
    self.conn.rollback()
    self.returnerr['ID']    = 0
    self.returnerr['ERROR_CD']   = error.code
    self.returnerr['ERROR_MSG']  = error.message
    self.returnerr['TABLE_NAME'] = self.debug_val
```

Comment: Any idea what the value of `error` is if it is a string?

Comment: When handling errors/exceptions you should avoid using the now deprecated `except EXCEPTION, EXC` and instead `except EXCEPTION as EXC` or for multiple exception catching: `except (EXCEPTION1, EXCEPTION2) as EXC`

Comment: @InbarRose: That's a red herring and not the cause of the problem. Let's focus on the actual issue here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Probably right, but still, no harm in a simple comment/suggestion.

Comment: You should *not* re-ask the same question though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your exception handling is broken. You're getting some sort of error oracle database error thrown inside your try block and it would be useful to see it, but the line in your code

```
 self.returnerr['ERROR_CD']   = error.code
```

is throwing the error you're reporting because the "error" object is just a string and doesn't have a `.code` attribute.

Also...

```
delete from a table
```

Doesn't look like the actual DML you are attempting. Why don't you post the actual DELETE statement and maybe we can see if there's a syntax error. If this is your literal code, you need to read the documentation. I believe it's supposed to look more like:

```
import cx_Oracle as db
conn = db.connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE somecolumn = someval")
conn.commit()
conn.close
```

Comment: That is *why* the OP is *asking* this question. He normally can expect `error` to be a [`cx_Oracle._Error` object](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html#exception-handling).

Comment: Well, without seeing the actual DML we have no idea how we're getting into the `except` block. If this is OP's literal code, than I believe I answered his question in the second block of code I provided. In any event, adding `print ex` to the top of the `except` block would be very illustrative since we have no idea what the original exception is.

Comment: That is *not the point*. The point is that he is catching `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError` which is documented to have one argument, an `cx_Oracle._Error` object. And suddenly that is not the case, and that is indeed weird. Let's figure out what the value *is* in that case.

Comment: And it cannot *possibly* be literal code, because then he'd never get to that exception handler. :-) To me it is obvious that the OP elided that part, because it could very well be that it is not relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It has to be a Database error to have brought us to the exception block. OP does seem to be doing what he's supposed to per the documentation. Very strange.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs...The problem as mentioned above is binding the element in the delete stmt.. I was trying to bind a variable with a list item..Once I fixed it , it worked..thanks